# Does Kafka supports different consumers reads the same partition with different offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-partition

Does Kafka supports different consumers reads the same partition with different offsets?

A partition:

```
              |------------Consumer 2, offset 2
+---+---+---+---+----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | .. |  <---- a particular partition
+---+---+---+---+----+
  |______Consumer 1, offset 1

Is it possible?
```

Update (from official Kafka ):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. As you can see from the picture `C1` and `C3` are consuming `P0`. Maybe `C1` read 10 messages and `C3` read 5. The only important thing is that `C1` and `C3` are not in the same consumer group. Two consumers from the same group cannot consume the same partition.

Comment: How about offsets? Do the the different groups consumers who read the same partition use the different offset? Where the offsets stored? If another group consumer join to them, will the 3rd offset be created? If a consumer will complete reading on the half way (BTW how the consumers tells to kafka it done?) will the offset be deleted?

Comment: Yes, committed offsets are stored for each consumer GROUP on each partition. Hence individual consumers can come and go in which case rebalance occurs and whichever consumer in a group picks up the partition, they start from that offset. These offsets are stored on a special topic - if you use the console client to list all topics you can see its details.

Answer (score 1):

No, for a partition in a topic only one consumer can read the partition at a time. And once those messages are read, the next consumer who is allotted that topic will read the next offset which hasn't been committed.

You can configure the consumer with `--from-beginning` so that the next consumer can read all the messages in that partition.

Comment: Is the point of your answer: "this is possible, but not at the same time"?

Comment: Yes. @J.J.Beam this can't happen concurrently.

Comment: got it, thank you. So how a consumer can "finish" consumes?

Comment: When all the messages produced are read by the consumer, or basically when a consumer stops consuming any messages.

Comment: Is it a consuming session there? Or some timeout after which Kafka can decided the consumer stopped to consume?

Comment: And what if consumers are belonging to different groups? Can they read the same partition?

Comment: Regarding a consumer stopping, usually consumer applications just consume and process in a loop. However if a consumer doesn't poll for a certain amount of time (5 minutes by default) then it is assumed to have gone and its partitions will be reassigned to the remaining consumers in the group. This can sometimes happen simply because a consumer is slow processing a batch, which is why generally Kafka adheres to 'at least once' semantics. Additionally, there is a background heartbeat thread. If the consumer is stopped and hence that thread dies, the rebalance happens after a shorter period